# Swift JSON Decoder Error: Missing something

Tags: json, swift, encoding, mapbox, decoding

I am using a JSON encoder and decoder to be able to save a custom object to my user defaults. The object I am trying to encode and decode is a Mapbox Directions Route Object (See their documentation here: [Mapbox Route](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/directions/api/2.0.0/Classes/Route.html#/s:16MapboxDirections5RouteC4legs5shape8distance18expectedTravelTime07typicalhI0ACSayAA0C3LegCG_4Turf10LineStringVSgS3dSgtcfc)

I have successfully used a JSON Encoder and Decoder for many things in my app. But for some reason, I can't get it to work with the Route object. Following is my JSON Encoder:

```
//Encode route response Object to pass it to Defaults
do {
     // Create JSON Encoder
     let encoder = JSONEncoder()
     // Encode Note
     let encodedRoute = try encoder.encode(route)
     // Write/Set Data
     UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedRoute, forKey: "routeObject")
     print("Encoded route Object.")
     } catch {
          print("Unable to Encode route (\(error))")
     }
```

Note that the console prints "Encoded route Object.", which should mean it worked.

Following now is my Decoder, which does not work and throws me the error I added to the `catch` statement:

```
//Read/Get response Object
if let encodedRoute = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "routeObject") {
     do {
          // Create JSON Decoder
          let decoder = JSONDecoder()

          // Decode Note
          myRoute = try decoder.decode(MapboxDirections.Route.self, from: encodedRoute)
          print("Successfully decoded route Object!")
          } catch {
               print("Unable to Decode route. Error: \(error)")
          }
}
```

The error which I get is: "Unable to Decode route. Error: missingOptions". Since RouteOptions is part of the Route object, I am guessing that something went wrong while encoding or decoding, leading to a missing piece of the object. I tried encoding and decoding a RouteResponse (which contains multiple Routes), which returned me "missingCredentials". Again, Credentials is part of RouteResponse. What could I have done wrong? Both classes are working well otherwise and both already use many other Mapbox functions, so it cannot be something with the imports or such.

If there is a workaround to pass an object to another class without using getter and setters (which bugs also), I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: "missingOptions" Is that the full error message?

Comment: @Larme yes it is, except if there is a way to see a more detailed error message. It's the complete console print.

Comment: It's custom decoding from MapBox API, usually error is more explicit. See https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/directions/api/2.0.0-alpha.2/Enums/DirectionsCodingError.html#/s:16MapboxDirections0B11CodingErrorO14missingOptionsyA2CmF

Answer (score 2):

It's a custom error thrown by the MapBox API.

From [their code](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-directions-swift/blob/f46b02eeb196c4b23e96bc3f1a303266010e96ef/Sources/MapboxDirections/DirectionsError.swift):

```
/**
 An error that occurs when encoding or decoding a type defined by the MapboxDirections framework.
 */
public enum DirectionsCodingError: Error {
    /**
     Decoding this type requires the `Decoder.userInfo` dictionary to contain the `CodingUserInfoKey.options` key.
     */
    case missingOptions
...
}
```

In [Route](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-directions-swift/blob/f852eb8520b616dd0082b163e6e59bba7a069633/Sources/MapboxDirections/Route.swift), we can see the comments on `init(from decoder:)`, which is, under the hood called by `decoder.decode(_:from:)`:

```
/**
 Initializes a route from a decoder.
 
 - precondition: If the decoder is decoding JSON data from an API response, the `Decoder.userInfo` dictionary must contain a `RouteOptions` or `MatchOptions` object in the `CodingUserInfoKey.options` key. If it does not, a `DirectionsCodingError.missingOptions` error is thrown.
 - parameter decoder: The decoder of JSON-formatted API response data or a previously encoded `Route` object.
 */
public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    try super.init(from: decoder)
}
```

So you need to put, something like:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.underInfo = [CodingUserInfoKey.options: someRouteOptions]
// or
decoder.underInfo = [CodingUserInfoKey.options: someMatchOptions]
```

I don't use that framework, but I guess that the usage on why which one to use should appear on their documentation or the git repo code. You can search maybe for `RouteOptions`/`MatchOptions` there.

Comment: I come to the same conclusion now, reading the documentation. However, I am kind of lost trying to find what key to put there. I have created an issue on their github. Seems to me as this should not be this way. Thanks anyway!